Why does Wolframscript handle the standard output differently than the regular terminal?
Here's the code:
$TerminalWidth = 140;
slice = StringRepeat["-",$TerminalWidth];
Print /@ {slice,"simple",slice};
Print[slice,"\n","simple","\n",slice];

You can run it within the Wolframscript terminal interface, or you can run the code so that the standard output is read by your terminal emulator outside of the custom Wolframscript interface.
I would assume that both printing versions would be the same, as it occurs outside of Wolframscript, but within it the second version is different than the first.
(And that difference breaks the aesthetic of some code I'm running).
I understand that I could just run code like the first version rather than the second.
Could you help me understand why, within Wolframscript, the two versions print differently?
Also, since it's relevant, are there some good links to gather some context on that custom Wolframscript interface?

I think that it has to do with the FormatType option for $Output. Changing it may get you the behavior you seek. Here is the behavior I observe on Windows.
SetOptions[$Output, FormatType -> ScriptForm];



'SetOptions[ $Output, FormatType->ScriptForm]' does have the intended effect on 'Print["a","\nb","c"]' within the custom Wolframscript interface. However, there's no documentation for 'ScriptForm' that I could find. It does seem to be referenced in '$OutputForms'. There are three mentions of it in StackExchange, none with elaborate explanation. So I'm not really sure ScriptForm entails. I'll keep it in mind though. Thanks for the input!
My solution will be to replace all instances of Print with a custom function that effectively does Print@StringJoin["a","\nb","c"].

If I understand your problem correctly, then the explanation is found in the documentation for Print:

Print[expr1, expr2, ...] prints expri concatenated together, effectively using Row.

So let's use a simpler example:
Print["A\nBC"]
Print["A", "\nB", "C"]


Here you can clearly see that Print[x, y] is not the same as Print[x]; Print[y], as you might be used in some other programming languages.
You can simulate the same behaviour in a notebook by using OutputForm:
"A\nBC" // OutputForm
Row[{"A", "\nB", "C"}] // OutputForm



Fair, that makes sense. And 'Row@List["A", "\nB", "C"] // StandardForm' will print as intended in a notebook but will return a TemplateBox within the custom Wolframscript interface. Obviously the solution is to replace Print with a custom function that does Print@StringJoin["A","\nB","C"]. (So that the code runs as intended across all interfaces). It just seems a bit odd that 'Print' works as intended in the Mathematica FE/IDE and when passing code through Wolframscript, but not within the custom Wolframscript interface. (btw, what is the proper name for it?).
